# Basic Locking in HTTP Server with Python

Tags: python, multithreading, http, server, locking

I am implementing a basic HTTP server that interrogates a database via PostGRESQL.
In order to handle multiple requests I need to create a thread in the server for each one, and I am currently doing this.

```
class MyServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
def __init__(self, server_address, handler_class):
    super().__init__(server_address=server_address, RequestHandlerClass=handler_class)
    self.KEEP_ALIVE = True

def run(self):
    while self.KEEP_ALIVE:
        self.handle_request()
```

and, for example, my do_DELETE method is done like this:

```
    def do_DELETE(self):
    # Get ID from the request path
    config_id = self.path[2:]

    # Connect to DB
    connection_db, cursor = self.connect_to_DB()

    with connection_db:

        # Check if the config to delete exists
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM configuration WHERE id=%s', (config_id, ))
        res = cursor.fetchall()

        # If the config to delete exists, the operation is done. Otherwise an error message is sent back
        if len(res) != 0:
            cursor.execute('DELETE FROM configuration WHERE id=%s', (config_id,))
            response_code = 200
            answer = OPERATION_SUCCESSFUL
        else:
            # Send error message back
            response_code = 400
            answer = NO_SUCH_ID_ERROR
        content_type = 'text/plain'
        self.reply(response_code=response_code, content_type=content_type, answer=answer)
```

I would like to make it so that, in the do_DELETE method, the part with the two queries to the DB is atomic, i.e. it should lock on a resource visible by all the threads... but I have no idea on how to do it. Can you help me?

Comment: What about locking the table within postgres ?

Comment: That's an idea, but how? The problem is that I should lock the table before the first statement and release it after the second, with two transaction. Is there a way to prevent the DBMS to release the lock after the first transaction?

Comment: Have a look there: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-lock.html